# Does it matter how many spaces exist in terminal commands?

Tags: linux, macos, unix, terminal, language

For those of us humans trying to learn terminal languages and codes, does it matter how many spaces are or are not included in the commands and scripts of various languages? For instance, is there any difference between:

```
grep | bagelyum
```

and

```
grep|bagelyum
```

?

Are there languages and instances where hitting the spacebar too many times (or not enough) will influence the outcome of a command? As a newbie, what I've found to be intimidating about learning terminal languages is my concern about minutiae like this. In human sociolinguistics, gaps and silences can be meaningful. But what about computer languages?

Comment: The documentation for the CLI, shell or program that you're using would provide the most accurate answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was about to say "generally speaking, the amount of whitespace doesn't matter" and then I started thinking of all the exceptions and inconsistencies and it got too much.

So here's a holistic answer instead. Like any interactive system evolved over time (human language is a damn good example), the answer is *"yes, and no, well, it depends, it's complicated"*. There are exceptions, inconsistencies, and so-called "standards" or "norms" that have arisen out of an overriding desire to maintain backwards compatibility over correctness.

So enjoy the mess. To refer to your *sociolinguistics* analogy, don't forget that the gaps and silences you speak of may be interpreted completely differently depending on country/culture. Moving from one OS to another, one command interpreter to another, one scripting language to another, etc., can be like moving from one country or culture to another.

Answer (score 1):

Whitespace (spaces, tabs, etc.) is ignored in many programming languages however it is important in others, such as `erlang`. Indentations (whitespace) is important in `python` as well.

Comment: so spacebar entries = "whitespace?" what about carriage returns (i.e., shift+enter)? are those also "whitespace?"

Comment: is it appropriate to compare whitespace to commenting/uncommenting, like with `#` or some other symbol?

Comment: @gradstudent: // "Whitespace" usually means spaces & tabs; though in some languages carriage returns are also included, in others not. // No, it's not even _close_ to commenting/uncommenting.

Comment: @gradstudent grawity answered the part about white space. Normally when you run code through a compiler it'll remove the white space and comments and then make the code into machine language. The formatting and comments are to increase the readability of the code for the programmers.